# How to skip TLS cert check for crictl (containerd CR) while pulling the images from private repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssl, containerd, crictl

I have installed k8s 1.24 version and containerd (containerd://1.5.9) is the CR for my setup (ubuntu 20.04).

I have also installed docker on my VM and have added my private repository under /etc/docker/daemon.json with the following changes:

```
{   "insecure-registries" : ["myPvtRepo.com:5028"] }
```

When I am running `docker pull myPvtRepo:123/image` after login to my pvt repo by using `docker login myPvtRepo:123` command, I am able to pull the images while running the same command with `crictl pull myPvtRepo:123/image`, I am facing:

> E0819 06:49:01.200489  162610 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from
> image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to
> pull and unpack image "myPvtRepo.com:5028/centos:latest": failed to
> resolve reference "myPvtRepo.com:5028/centos:latest": failed to do
> request: Head https://myPvtRepo.com::5028/v2/centos/manifests/latest:
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
> image="myPvtRepo.com::5028/centos:latest" FATA[0000] pulling image:
> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image
> "myPvtRepo.com::5028/centos:latest": failed to resolve reference
> "myPvtRepo.com:5028/centos:latest": failed to do request: Head
> https://myPvtRepo.com::5028/v2/centos/manifests/latest: x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority

FYI, I have modified /etc/containerd/config.toml with below content.

```
version = 2

[plugin."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."myPvtRepo.com:5028".tls]
    insecure_skip_verify = true

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
     endpoint = ["https://myPvtRepo.com:5028", "https://myPvtRepo.com:5038", "https://myPvtRepo.com:5037",
 "https://myPvtRepo.com:5039"]

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."IP:5000"]
     endpoint = ["http://IP:5000"]

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."IP:5000"]
     endpoint = ["http://IP:5000"]
```

I have also modified containerd's endpoint to point to containerd's sock.

Can you please help me out to understand and fix that even after setting `insecure_skip_verify = true` for my pvt repository and restarting the containerd service why I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I got a solution:

```
cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
curl -L --remote-name http://your-artifacts.com/xyz-bundle.crt
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```

This one work for me.

Also make sure to update your endpoints under /etc/crictl.yaml

```
runtime-endpoint: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 
image-endpoint: "" 
timeout: 0 
debug: false 
pull-image-on-create: false 
disable-pull-on-run: false
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that RootCA cert is necessary here.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to specify the `hosts.toml` file for the private registry and add `skip-verify = true`.

ref: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md

Steps:

1. create folders: `mkdir -p /etc/containerd/certs.d/<your registry>`
2. add these config in `/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

   ```ini
   [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
     config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
   ```
3. create and edit `hosts.toml` under the just created folder

   ```ini
   server = "https://<your registry>"


   [host."https://<your registry>"]
     capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
     skip_verify = true
   ```